# $X$ - regular, $A \subset X$ - closed $\Rightarrow \ \ X/A$ - quotient space is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

Could you tell me how to prove that if $X$ is a regular space , $ \ A \subset X$ is closed, then $ X/A$ (quotient space) is Hausdorff?

I know what the topology of a quotient space looks like. If $q: X \rightarrow X/A$, then $U \subset X/A$ is open $\iff \ \ q^{-1}(U)$ is open. But I don't know how to use it here.

Could you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Regularity means you have two disjoint open sets $A \subset U$ and $x \in V$ for all $x \notin A$.

Comment: Yes, it does.  Quotient mapping is surjective, so each singleton in the quotient space is the image of a singleton in X and this singleton is closed in X because X is also T1. In X/A we treat A as a point, but I don't know what to do next. Could you help a bit more?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm right and I hope you'll correct me if I'm wrong. $q$ sends all $x \notin A$ to themselves and "clusters" all $x \in A$ to one point in $X/A$. Does that mean that if in $X, \ \ x \notin A$ there exist disjoint, open $U,V$ such that $A \subset U$ and $x \in V$, then, since in $X/A \ \ A$ is one point, it is Hausdorff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically just do it.

First, note that the quotient mapping works as follows:  $$ q(x) = \begin{cases}
x, &\text{if }x \notin A \\
A, &\text{if }x \in A.
\end{cases}$$

So let's pick two distinct points $x,y \in X / A$.  What follows is a basic outline, with the details left to be filled in.

- If neither point is $A$, then $x,y \in X \setminus A$ (which is open in $X$), and we can use the Hausdorffness of $X$ (and a parenthetical observation above) to help separate them in $X / A$.
- If one of them, say $y$, is $A$, then we know that $x \in X \setminus A$, and we can instead turn to the regularity of $X$ to help separate these points in $X / A$.